# how to find out if a specific table exists in a dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

I have created an application which reads the records from excel files and 2D arrays and after merging them it will pass the data to `ds.table[x]`. i would like to know if there is a way for me to check if the `ds.table[x]` exist? and how can i do that in code behind ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check with the following if statement,

```
 if(ds.Tables.Contains("TableName"))
```

Comment: I've tried that before and it doesn't work. i think its because that statement checks whether if a table contains "thestring" while im looking for something like if ds contains table[x]

Comment: It _does_ work. See [`DataTableCollection.Contains` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ye3t49b6.aspx).

Comment: If you do not know the name of table, then you can just check the `ds.Tables.Count` is > than (int)x

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16146473/check-if-table-exists-with-if-statement-in-c for a few other solutions.